# How to add a subview to another view controller without going to that view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to realize this function: In the left slide-out menu, when I pick one picture, this picture will be generated on the home view controller. 
The link is the image shot. http://postimg.org/image/kcd3jhd6x/

And here is the code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let halfSizeOfView = 25.0
    let insetSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, CGFloat(Int(2 * halfSizeOfView)), CGFloat(Int(2 * halfSizeOfView))).size

    let pointX = CGFloat(UInt(arc4random() % UInt32(UInt(insetSize.width))))
    let pointY = CGFloat(UInt(arc4random() % UInt32(UInt(insetSize.height))))

    if(searchActive){
       imageName=filtered[indexPath.row]+".png"
    }else{
       imageName=data[indexPath.row]+".png"
    }

    let wid=UIImage(named: imageName)?.size.width
    let hei=UIImage(named: imageName)?.size.height
    let newImageView = ImageViewList(frame: CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, wid!, hei!))
    newImageView.image=UIImage(named: imageName)

    let vc=HomeViewController()
    vc.view.addSubview(newImageView)

}
```

Because I want to stay at slide-out menu when pressing the cell, So I can't do the performSegueWithIdentifier function. I also tried protocol passing value method, but it seems not working. Is anyone give a suggestion? Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your navigation structure? Is the slide-out menu a child of the `HomeViewController`?

Comment: No, slide-out menu is not a child of HomeViewController. They are independent

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a weak reference (`delegate`) to your `SideMenu` controller inside the `Home` controller.

- Implement protocol inside `SideMenu` controller

  ```
  protocol SideMenuDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
      func menuItemSelected(image: UIImage)
  }
  ```
- Add delegate to `SideMenu` controller

  ```
  weak var delegate: SideMenuDelegate?
  ```
- Set your `HomeController` instance as a delegate

  ```
  let homeVC = HomeViewController()
  let sideMenu = SideMenuController()
  sideMenu.delegate = homeVC
  ```
- Implement `SideMenuDelegate` protocol inside `HomeViewController` class

  ```
  class HomeViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuDelegate {
      func menuItemSelected(image: UIImage) {
          imageView.image = image
      }
  }
  ```
- When item selected in `SideMenu` call method

  ```
  delegate?.menuItemSelected(image)
  ```

Both `SideMenu` and `Home` controllers should be created somewhere simultaneously. It might be `AppDelegate` or `MainViewController`, no matter.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quite patient answer! I tried this before I posted the question. But there is a little difference. sideMenu.delegate = homeVC shows error that says "cannot assign value of type HomeViewController to type "SideMenuDelegate?"

Comment: @CihaiSun Did you put `class HomeViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuDelegate`?

Comment: Yep,I fixed that error, but when I run the test and press the cell in the SideMenu, no picture will be shown on the HomeViewController. here is the code I edited according to your suggestion:

Comment: I put "
        let homeVC=HomeViewController()
        let sideMenu=LeftViewController()
        sideMenu.delegate=homeVC"  under the did selectRowAtIndexPath function of SideMenuController and call the" self.delegate?.menuItemsSelected(newImageView)    then in the menuItemsSelected(image view:UIImageView){ self.view.addSubView(image view)}

Comment: @Cihai Sun Firstly, pass image, not UIImageView here: `self.delegate?.menuItemsSelected(newImageView)`. Then, place all layout logic in viewDidLoad() method in HomeViewController (i mean create and add UIImageView, set frame or constraints, background color and etc.). And don't forget to set correct `window?.rootViewController`.